# Rails autoload without module subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, activesupport

I understand the reason for which new Rails engines create an **engine_name** subfolder for each of the standard folders. However I wonder if it is possible to construct an engine that does not require subfolders.

For example, given this model:

```
module MyEngine
   class Person
   ...
   end
end
```

It is supposed to be in the file `app/models/my_engine/person.rb` but I would like to have it in `app/models/person.rb`

By default this change breaks Rails autoloading. At worst I could live with manually loading dependencies, but I really do not want to lose the auto-reload feature.

Is it possible to have auto-load and auto-reload without subfolders? (while still using the module namespace)

Comment: Totally aggree, those subdirectories are really annoying and, at least in theory, absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: The subfolders are there because ActiveSupport requires a matching folder for each module, so I am already not very optimistic of solving this. However outside an engine it is a great idea, because it prepares the code to be refactored out.